# Airflow scheduler is not picking up new tasks after upgrade from 1.10.4 to 2.2.3

Tags: airflow

I recently upgraded from airflow 1.10.4 to 2.2.3

Everything seems to be working fine, except when I create a new task, the scheduler does not pick it up (unless I restart it)

It also does not appear under the DAG tasks in the server.

How do I go about fixing this?

Comment: can you please explain what you did exactly to upgrade? (reset the database or you used `airflow db upgrade`?

Comment: airflow db upgrade